# Cannot install fpp2 package

Tags: r, forecasting

*** EDIT: Problem solved**

I re-install R with the newest version. Then installed forecast and xts packages, and it worked.

---

I tried to install "fpp2" package, and it seemed ok as R downloaded and installed many things. But when installation was done, R gave a warning that the package "had non-zero exit status". 
Calling `library(fpp2)` gives an error that "there is no package called ‘fpp2’". I use both of the following ways, none works.

```
install.packages('fpp2')
install.packages('fpp2', dependencies = TRUE)
```

I also tried both yes and no options for the question "Do you want to install from sources the packages which need compilation?", but none of them works.

Do you know why this happens?

Comment: It would help if you provided more information, such as the actual console output (including errors) and `sessionInfo()`.

Comment: That package in its ccurrent form for R 3.5.1 has dependencies:  'ggplot2', 'forecast (>= 8.3)', 'fma', 'expsmooth', 'x13binary', 'fma’, ‘Mcomp’, ‘seasonal’, ‘vars’. You should first check their status _and_ you should look at the "DESCRIPTION" file, as well as its support site: https://github.com/robjhyndman/fpp2-package